# Express app's protected routes are not responding in stage or production

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I implemented authentication using JWT, the cookie options are written as below

```
expires: new Date(
        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    secure:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ||
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'stage',
    httpOnly: true,
};
```

My app is currently being hosted on AWS EC2 instance, when I hit the routes that not protected, I get a response but when I reach out to protected ones (on browser or Postman), it just keeps loading without any valid response or error message thrown back.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided isn't sufficient to rectify the problem but in the above code I see a mistake and I assume you are using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) then in that case the expire time is given in `expiresIn` instead of `expire` so it should be like this.

```
expiresIn : ...
```

Comment: I'm not actually very sure if the issue is even code related as it runs smoothly locally or perhaps it has to do with the EC2 Instance I'm running.

Comment: You are getting any exceptions?

Comment: Not at all, the page just keeps loading without any errors in network tab or console log. My guess is that it might have something to do with my JWT.

Comment: Not on the frontend but on the backed, there is no request received at all for it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured what my issue is - I needed to use my login routes first, please ignore this thread. I will delete it shortly.